# Database not being created

Tags: ios, sqlite, nsfilemanager

I have a piece of code that adds a database if it has not been created yet. 
Here is the code

```
-(void) checkAndCreateDatabase{
  // Check if the SQL database has already been saved to the users phone, if not then copy it over

  NSString *path=[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

  NSString *database_path=[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Favorite_Database.sqlite"];

  // Create a FileManager object, we will use this to check the status
  // of the database and to copy it over if required

  // Check if the database has already been created in the users filesystem
  BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:database_path];

  // If the database already exists then return without doing anything
  if(success) {
      //[fileManager removeFileAtPath:databasePath handler:nil];   
      return;
  }
  // If not then proceed to copy the database from the application to the users filesystem

  // Get the path to the database in the application package
  NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Favorite_Database.sqlite"];

  // Copy the database from the package to the users filesystem
  [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:database_path error:nil];

}
```

When it hits the line `BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:database_path];` it just skips and the rest and continues on. I doesn't get to the if statement. I need it to check so I can add this database

How can I get it to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

Log out the path so if you're running in the emulator, you can see if the file actually exists by going to that path in terminal.  You can also use sqlite cmdline to inspect the db file.

Here's code from a sample of mine that does a similar task.

It (1) checks if the database exists, if not, (2) it copies it from the bundle and (3) opens it.

Hope it helps ...

```
- (BOOL)ensureDatabaseOpen: (NSError **)error
{
    // already created db connection
    if (_contactDb != nil)
    {
        return YES;
    }

    NSLog(@">> ContactManager::ensureDatabaseOpen");    
    if (![self ensureDatabasePrepared:error])
    {
        return NO;
    }

    const char *dbpath = [_dbPath UTF8String]; 
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_contactDb) != SQLITE_OK &&
        error != nil)
    {
        *error = [[[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:@"ContactsManager" code:1000 userInfo:nil] autorelease];
        return NO;
    }

    NSLog(@"opened");

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)ensureDatabasePrepared: (NSError **)error
{
    // already prepared
    if ((_dbPath != nil) &&
        ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:_dbPath]))
    {
        return YES;
    }

    // db in main bundle - cant edit.  copy to library if !exist
    NSString *dbTemplatePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"contacts" ofType:@"db"];
    NSLog(@"%@", dbTemplatePath);

    NSString *libraryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    _dbPath = [libraryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"contacts.db"];

    NSLog(@"dbPath: %@", _dbPath);

    // copy db from template to library
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:_dbPath])
    {
        NSLog(@"db not exists");
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:dbTemplatePath toPath:_dbPath error:&error])
        {
            return NO;
        }

        NSLog(@"copied");
    }    

    return YES;    
}
```

Comment: On both my code and your code it stops at the `if (fileExistsAtPath)`  then just skips the rest without any errors

Comment: Hmmm - can you try adding a bunch of logging and run in the emulator and the device?  (trying to rule out file system/premissions etc... in the eumlator)

Comment: also - when you run in the emulator, make sure you can log out and visit that path in the terminal.

Comment: The logs for the dbPath seem fine. It still stops at that line and skips the remainder of the code in that method.

I have this code working in my other app and I tried to reproduce it by just adding a database to this project and copying code but its not working

Comment: I fixed it. I just had to remove the file and let the code replace it. Thanks for the help